# What is the difference between 箸【はし】 and 割【わ】り箸【ばし】?

Tags: meaning, words

What is the difference between 箸【はし】 and 割【わ】り箸【ばし】? Do both terms refer to chopsticks?

Comment: You mean the difference 箸 and 割り箸? If so, watabashi should be waribashi isn't it?

Comment: I mistakenly heard it as watabashi. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

割り箸 are disposable (usually wooden) chopsticks you will get in a restaurant. They are made from one piece of wood. You will have to break them (割る) into their two parts to use them.

箸 is the general term.